# use of <!-- # in HTML or ASP.net programming

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, comments

The title says it all, can anyone enlighten me what the number sign is for in what I assume is simply an html comment block?

```
<!-- #
```

Comment: Read this http://the-stickman.com/web-development/why-you-shouldnt-use-html-comments-that-begin-with-a-hash-symbol-on-apache/

Comment: Your title does not say it all. `#` is part of the comment, not the syntax for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are mod_include in Apache HTTP Server.

For eg.

```
<!--#element attribute=value attribute=value ... -->
```

For more read [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_include.html) and [this](http://the-stickman.com/web-development/why-you-shouldnt-use-html-comments-that-begin-with-a-hash-symbol-on-apache/)